# How to connect 2 Raspberry Pi Camera Module v2 to a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, camera

I am making an underwater drone and want to use 2 cameras, in order to get depth perception. I want to connect 2 Raspberry Pi Camera Modules v2 to a Raspberry Pi 3 but don't know how.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible as there is only one camera connector on the board? You will likely need to use USB for the second camera.

Comment: If you search for "raspberry pi camera multiplexer" you'll find some hardware.  I can't vouch for any of it though.

Answer (score 3):

If depth perception is required, that means running the two cameras simultaneously. That's not possible with the multiplexer which only permits recording from a single camera at a given moment. Stereoscopic capture simply isn't possible with a regular Pi. It *is* possible with the [compute module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/compute-module-3-launch/) which has two CSI connectors (and as much computing power as a Pi 3 since the launch of the CM3 (linked). Stereo capture/recording is supported in the firmware on this particular platform, however unless you use the IO development kit, the general assumption with the compute module is that you'll build your own interface board for it.